# ORACLE- If Column contains only String then True else False

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

Suppose I have 2 columns, the first column contains alphanumeric as well as a mixture of characters eg. abc12$$, abc, 123, re12. 
The second column contains only numbers but with different lengths.

I have to find if the first column contains only alphabets and the second column contains only 9 digits then True else False

Can you please help me in that?

Below is the Query you can modify

```
with temp(name) as (select 'abc' from dual
union select '123abc' from dual
union select '1abc3' from dual
union select 'abc3' from dual
union select 'ab3c' from dual)
select * from temp;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first column" and "second column"? Your sample data have only one column. In case you mean first and second **row** - how do you determine the order of rows?

Answer (score 5):

To check if a column only contains characters, you can use:

```
case when regexp_like(aColumn, '^[[:alpha:]]*$') then 'true' else 'false' end
```

This considers an empty string as a character string; if you want to get false for empty strings, you may want to edit `[[:alpha:]]*` into `[[:alpha:]]+`.

How it works:

- `^`: the beginning of the string
- `[[:alpha:]]*` zero or more occurrences of an alphabetic character
- `$`: the end of the string

To check that the second column only contains 9 digit numbers, you may need

```
case when regexp_like(aColumn, '^\d{9}$') then 'true' else 'false' end
```

here `\d{9}` means "exactly 9 occurrences of a digit".

You can easily use both expressions to do both checks together, something like

```
case
  when regexp_like(column_1, '^[[:alpha:]]*$')  AND
       regexp_like(column_2, '^\d{9}$')
  then 'true'
  else 'false'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

this might help

```
with temp(name,numb) as 
(select 'abc',123456789 from dual
union select '123abc',123 from dual
union select '1abc3',123 from dual
union select 'abc3',123 from dual
union select 'ab3c',123 from dual)
select name,case when regexp_like(name, '^[a-zA-Z]*$') and 
regexp_like(numb, '^[^a-zA-Z]*$') and length(to_char(numb))=9 then 'true' else 'false' end from temp;
```

Comment: this could be a better solution if you want to check if the second column is a number and its length =9.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to ask for the following :

```
with temp(str,nr) as
 (select 'abc' str,123456789 nr
    from dual
  union
  select '123abc$',12345678
    from dual
  union
  select '1abc3#' ,1234567
    from dual
  union
  select 'abc3'   ,123456
    from dual
  union
  select 'ab3c'   ,12345 
    from dual)
select case when ( t.str = regexp_substr(str,'[a-zA-Z]+') and length(nr)=9 ) then 'True' 
            else 'False' 
        end result,
       str, nr 
  from temp t
 order by length(nr) desc;

RESULT  STR        NR
------  -------    ---------
True    abc        123456789
False   123abc$    12345678
False   1abc3#     1234567
False   abc3       123456
False   ab3c       12345
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46f83/25)